# How to use Thread.sleep(); in selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I cant use `Thread.sleep();`

Exception:

> "Unhandled exception type InterruptedException" is thrown in Selenium Webdriver.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: A suggestion: Avoid using Thread.sleep(), instead use WebDriver's waiting mechanism explicit wait.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the sleep() function, this may throw [InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html). To prevent this it's handling is mandatory.

You can use try-catch:

```
try{
Thread.sleep(5000);
}
catch(InterruptedException ie){
}
```

OR throws:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

If you are using a standard IDE to code, it will automatically give you an option to add this when you hover over the error displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add your code in try - catch block like:

try{
--CODE
Thread.Sleep(1000);
}catch(Expression ex){
system.out.print(ex.getmessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `Thread.sleep()` in your Selenium tests at all. `Thread.sleep()` makes current thread to cease execution; this could lead to problems when running tests in parallel.

As alternative, you can use [pause](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#pause(java.time.Duration)) method of `Actions` class.